# Reset input type date value ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker

What i have in my project is a date picker with a reset button next to it, after user select date from date picker, the date picker will show the selected date.
[See this image if you have dont get it yet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvSsS.png)

And what i want is to reset the date value back to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3fv7.png) by clicking reset button.

And here is my [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Kjt.png)

I did setting value back to null using useState hook onClick the button, using useRef hook, but nothing works. Any help?

Comment: Does that work setting `empty string` instead of `null` ?

Comment: is the mm/dd/yyyy a place holder ?

Comment: @Codenewbie i didnt described the placeholder, so i think that is default placeholder. I did setting to empty string, still not work.

Comment: would be better if you add a working example .... use codesandbox,stackblitz for that

Answer (score 0):

Which datepicker package do you use? This example works with react-datepicker:

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";

const [dateValue, setDateValue] = useState(null);

<DatePicker
    selected={dateValue}
    onChange={d => setDateValue(d)}
/>
<button onClick={() => setDateValue(null)}>Reset</button>
```

Comment: Im not using any library im using input type date html5 tag, but thanks for the suggestion for react-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using null, and simply change the value to empty string

```
dateRef.current =  '';
```